# Why does the webflux client give a 404?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a webflux client to connect to a remote websocket. There is an example websocket located at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. I can have my browser make a wss request there simply by pressing "connect". In my browser developer toolbar I can then see that a succesful request is made to wss://echo.websocket.org/?encoding=text

This url is also mentioned in https://stackify.com/reactive-spring-5/ (the code there doesn't work because "input" is not defined).

However, when I try to access the same url from spring boot 2.0.0 with webflux, I get a 404:

```
@PostConstruct
public void run() throws URISyntaxException {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
    Flux<String> r =
            webClient.get().uri("wss://echo.websocket.org/?encoding=text")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                    .log();

    r.subscribe(res -> System.out.println("ok: " + res), ex -> System.out.println(ex));
}
```

error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: ClientResponse has erroneous status code: 404 Not Found
```

My best guess is that it somehow does not work with urls that start with "wss://". Can I change the code so that the request will be successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClient` is not a WebSocket client, `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` (mentioned in the article you linked) is a `WebSocketClient`. Please use this instead.